# Create a spreadsheet in specific folder using GSpread v5.4.0

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I know this question has been asked before, but it appears that the `gspread` library has removed the ability to create a workbook in a specific folder.

[The latest docs don't have a folder_id option](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#creating-a-spreadsheet)

[The previous version does have a folder_id option](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.0/api.html?highlight=create#gspread.Client.create)

As such, I'm getting an error with this code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import os


credPathRoot = os.path.expanduser('myjsonPath')
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credPathRoot, scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

spreadSheetTitle = 'NewSpreadsheetDelete'
folderId = '###FolderID###'

workbook = gc.create(spreadSheetTitle, folder_id=folderId)
```

When I run this, I get the error `TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'folder_id'` which tells me the folder_id parameter was deleted. Is there a new way that I can create my spreadsheet in a specific folder?

Comment: About `The latest docs don't have a folder_id option`, when I saw https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/client.html?highlight=create#gspread.Client.create `folder_id` is existing. And, when I tested the latest version (v5.6.0) your script of `workbook = gc.create(spreadSheetTitle, folder_id=folderId)` works. So, how about confirming it again?

Comment: Which version of gspread do you have? You can see by running `pip show gspread` or `python -m pip show gspread`. I am using the latest (`5.6.2`) and do not get this error. The only thing I can think is if somehow the `create` function has been overwritten. Also try `print(help(gc.create))` to see the signature and docstring of the function

Comment: I just updated my gspread and it's "working" now, but I'm getting a different type of error. `gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'File not found: ###FolderID###.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'fileId'}], 'code': 404, 'message': 'File not found: ###FolderID###.'}`. This tells me that it wasn't expecting a folder_id but instead a spreadsheet_id? I'm almost positive my remote python has access to this folder as I use gspread to manage info in sheets within the folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `File not found: ###FolderID###.`, in this case, it is considered that you might be using `###FolderID###` as the folder ID. If my understanding is correct, as a simple modification, how about testing it as `folderId = 'root'`? By this, the Spreadsheet is created to the root folder. This is a test. When you want to put the specific folder, please modify `###FolderID###` to your folder ID.

Answer (score 0):

this is odd, when I check your link I see the documentation mentions the `folder_id` parameter.

I check every version of the documentation from `v5.6.0` to `v5.3.0` and they all include the parameter `folder_id`.

About the latest doc: the parameter is here and mentioned in the API
See [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/client.html#gspread.Client.create)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old topic, maybe there are other people facing the same issue (just like I did).
The problem was: the python service_account needs to have access to the Google Folder. Once I have granted permission, the code works and the folder_id is recognized.